# Выделить первую и последнюю ссылку

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть блок со ссылками. Количество ссылок в блоке может быть разное.
Я хочу выделить первую и последнюю ссылку, а точнее изменить border-radius . 
Если кол-во ссылок было бы фиксированным, я бы сделал это так:

```css
.menu_left {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 15px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu_left a {
 display: block;
 width: 210px;
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 padding: 6px;
}

.menu_left a:nth-child(1)  {
 border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.menu_left a:nth-child(4)  {
 border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="menu_left">
  <a href="/">Алюминиевые радиаторы</a>
  <a href="/">Биметаллические радиаторы</a>
  <a href="/">Комплектующие к радиаторам</a>
  <a href="/">Рекомендации по выбору радиатора</a>
 </div>
```

Как быть в моем случае?

Comment: используйте `first-child` и `last-child`

Answer (score 2):

Для этого есть специальные псевдоклассы [`:first-child`](https://webref.ru/css/first-child) и [`:last-child`](https://webref.ru/css/last-child).

```css
.menu_left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.menu_left a {
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  padding: 6px;
}
.menu_left a:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.menu_left a:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_left">
  <a href="/">Алюминиевые радиаторы</a>
  <a href="/">Биметаллические радиаторы</a>
  <a href="/">Комплектующие к радиаторам</a>
  <a href="/">Рекомендации по выбору радиатора</a>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. буду знать теперь

Answer (score 1):

Используйте псевдоклассы

[first-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/first-child)

[last-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/last-child)

```
a:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
a:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще есть такой вариант

[first-of-type](http://htmlbook.ru/css/first-of-type)

[last-of-type](http://htmlbook.ru/css/last-of-type)

[Различия между :nth-child и :nth-of-type](https://habrahabr.ru/post/119139/)

```css
.menu_left {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu_left a {
    display: block;
    width: 210px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    padding: 6px;
}

.menu_left a:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.menu_left a:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_left">
    <a href="/">Алюминиевые радиаторы</a>
    <a href="/">Биметаллические радиаторы</a>
    <a href="/">Комплектующие к радиаторам</a>
    <a href="/">Рекомендации по выбору радиатора</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[:first-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/first-child) и [:last-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/last-child) - эти псевдоклассы отвечают за обращение к первому и последнему элементу родителя.

```css
.menu_left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.menu_left a {
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  padding: 6px;
}
.menu_left a:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.menu_left a:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_left">
  <a href="/">Алюминиевые радиаторы</a>
  <a href="/">Биметаллические радиаторы</a>
  <a href="/">Комплектующие к радиаторам</a>
  <a href="/">Рекомендации по выбору радиатора</a>
</div>
```